# Adding a JPanel with 86,000 Components

Tags: java, swing, conways-game-of-life

So I found [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) recently, so I'm naturally addicted. It hasn't taken me long to find out that I am very limited by my computer's CPU. I've also found that, for whatever reason, I cannot add a `JPanel` with many `JComponents` to a `JFrame`.

So I have a `loop` that adds `86,400` `JLabels` to  a `JPanel`, which happens in ~1 second, but adding this `JPanel` to a `JFrame` takes ~2 minutes.

I understand I could use `java.awt.Graphics`, but I'd prefer to use `JLabels` because they automatically resize.

So my question: Why does this take so long to add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It basically takes so long because you're adding **86400 components** to it (and it takes long when adding the panel to the frame because then the components basically become "alive", or "realized" as they call it). **Don't do it, and don't try to fix it**.

Comment: I like how you phrased that. So you suggest I suck it up and use awt's graphics?

Comment: Definitely. (Theoretically, one could consider using the concept of a "Renderer" as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender - it is like a real component, but it is not realized or added anywhere, but instead used like a "stamp" for painting things. You can easily have a `JTable` with 90000 cells, for that matter. But the infrastructure that you'd have to write around this would probably not justify the benefit. You'd then still have to think about the layout and resizing and all that...)

Comment: A side note: I'd also not consider `Graphics` directly as the most suitable approach here. Instead, I'd create a `BufferedImage`. There, you can set the "cell colors" with `setRGB(x,y,rgb)` as you like. And you can trivially paint such an image into a component, in a way that always *fills* the whole component - so there isn't any "resizing" issue at all, and it's blazingly fast.

Comment: @Marco13 I normally don't use setRGB, I usually use a DataBufferInt, I like using them for whatever reason. I'll post my solution here when I feel like

Comment: When you create the image manually and want to do "high performance" operations on many `int` (A)RGB pixels (which is likely the case for conway) then `DataBufferInt` is even better. A bit less convenient than `setRGB`, but in some cases, the performance difference can be significant. A minor caveat is that *painting* the image that you obtained the `DataBufferInt` from can be slower - see the part about "Implementation Details" in this answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75667/46384 - but that should not be so relevant here.

Comment: @Marco13 when you mention `JTable`… of course, you can use `JTable` precisely for that, rather than implementing “the infrastructure”. Only when the cell size goes close to one pixel, I’d use a `BufferedImage` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `java.awt.Graphics`, I was able to remove this long period of lag:

```
public void render(int[][] cells) {

    int cellHeight = image.getHeight() /  cells.length;
    int cellWidth = image.getWidth() /  cells[0].length;

    for (int y = 0; y < cells.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < cells[y].length; x++) {

            int col = colors[cells[y][x]].getRGB();
            fillSquare(x * (cellWidth), y * (cellHeight), cellWidth, cellHeight, col);
        }
    }
}

// Could pass a java.awt.Rectangle here
private void fillSquare(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, int col) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[(x + xPos) + (y + yPos) * image.getWidth()] = col;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

For this method, it's important to keep the `JFrame`'s size proportional to the number of cells, this way there is no unused space within the `JFrame`.